# How to set DOM element height in Vue 3 script setup (Composition API)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to set a DOM element `height` to `200px` inside `script setup`:

```
<script setup>

const element = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    element.value.innerHeight = 200
    element.value.height = 200
    element.value.outerHeight = 200
})

</script>

<template>
  <div ref="element" class="w-6/12 p-4 mx-auto rounded border border-slate-400 bg-slate-50 shadow cursor-pointer hover:border-slate-600 hover:shadow-md transition mb-4 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500">

    // ...

  </div>
</template>
```

Although the `innerHeight/height/outerHeight` of the `element` ref object are changed, the `div` element is still rendered with `height: auto`.

How are `DOM element styles` in `composition api` controlled via `javascript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the height of an element by setting its `height/innerHeight/outerHeight`. You should update its style properties.

There are 2 methods to choose:

**Method 1:** set the style directly by js

```html
<script setup>

const element = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    element.value.style.height = '200px'
})

</script>
```

**Method 2:** Let Vue update the style for you via reactive variables

```html
<script setup>

const elementStyle = reactive({
  height: '100px'
})

onMounted(() => {
    elementStyle.height = '200px'
})

</script>

<template>
  <div :style="{ height: elementStyle.height }">

    // ...

  </div>
</template>
```